# Keyboard backlight turns on by itsself, Lenovo T440s

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, keyboard-backlight

Since the last kernel update to version 4.4.0-34 on Ubuntu 14.04, running on a Lenovo T440s, the keyboard backlight turns on by itself randomly. 
Does anyone encounter the same problem and/or knows how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a *workaround* which solved this problem for me. The keyboard backlight no longer turns on just by itself. Actually, it's off all the time. I think the way this solution works is that it completely cuts off the system from the keyboard backlight control. Luckily, you can still turn the backlight on if you want with the Fn shortcut.

You need to edit the file `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.UPower.conf`.

You need to change:

```
<allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.UPower"
send_interface="org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight"/>
```

To

```
<deny send_destination="org.freedesktop.UPower"
send_interface="org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight"/>
```

Finally you should reboot. Note that there are two lines that look very similar to each other in this particular file. Just to be sure, change `allow` to `deny` for both of them.

I found this solution [here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/keyboard-light-keeps-turning-on-after-login-and-or-unlock/6914/12) so thanks belongs to the original author.